# how to understand JSON.stringify value?

Tags: lightning, javascript, json, map, aura

Lets say, I have a map created in aura component controller. I want to send map to apex controler but unfortunately map cannot be serialized by JSON.stringify.
My code

```
JSON.stringify([...draftValues.entries()])
```

where draftValues is a map

server side

List obj= (List)JSON.deserializeUntyped('[["0017F00000gqDetQAE",{"ACCOUNTNUMBER":"CD451796 -- new","PHONE":"(512) 757-6000 --"}],["0017F00000gqDevQAE",{"NAME":"Pyramid Construction Inc. --"}]]');

how can I retrive Id (map key) and value (map.values) from this list of objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build the map in JS as an object:

```js
let jsMap = {
    '0017F00000gqDetQAE': {
        'ACCOUNTNUMBER': 'CD451796 -- new',
        'PHONE': '(512) 757-6000 --'
    },
    '0017F00000gqDevQAE': {
        'NAME': 'Pyramid Construction Inc. --'
    }
};

let stringForSendingToAPEX = JSON.stringify(jsMap);
```

Then you will be able to deserialize this string `stringForSendingToAPEX` into `Map<String, Object>` in the APEX:

```java
Map<String, Object> deserialized = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(stringForSendingToAPEX);
```

So, the IDs will be `deserialized.keySet()` and values:

```java
List<Map<String, Object>> values = new List<Map<String, Object>>();
for (Object obj : deserialized.values()) {
    values.add((Map<String, Object>) obj);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but how can I get all pairs e.g 'PHONE':'(512) ----' from Object?

Comment: Just use `String.valueOf` method. `String phone = String.valueOf(values[0].get('PHONE'))` (check that 'PHONE' key exists before)